# SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed error in boost::asio::async_read

Tags: c++, openssl, boost-asio

While exchanging messages at a high rate, I often encounter this error. The boost::asio::async_read fails with the message "error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac". This is on Win8.1 and VS2012.

While researching this error, I noticed that lots of people have been encountering it, but there is no definite cure for it. Some talk about a patch in s3_pkt.c file, I applied it, but didn't help.

My problem is exactly same as described here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.encryption.openssl.user/49443

Except, I am using boost::asio and not using openssl directly. I have openssl-1.0.1g on my PC. How do I get around this one?

Comment: I will parrot the conclusion made there: "It would be useful if you could work out which ciphersuite the affected
clients use."

Comment: Both client and server is my code, written using boost::asio. Should I change the default ciphersuite they would negotiate?

Comment: Alright, I cycled through many ciphers (using SSL_set_cipher_list), but problem still persists. It happens when intense simultaneous read and write operations are going on. I am setting the same cipher on both ends. Whether I use AES or non-AES cipher, it doesn't make a difference. It happens even if I use eNULL.

Comment: Is there a proxy involved? (Like Fiddler)? Also, how many threads run your ioservice?

Comment: No proxy, not even LAN, same machine. I am running one socket server with 4 clients, rapidly exchanging small messages in the same machine. Just one run() thread on the client, and 4 run() threads on the server side. This problem usually occurs on the client side, very rarely on server side.

Comment: yeah, I experience this too. Absolute deal breaker for using asio ssl

Comment: Oh, I finally solved it. It wasn't any asio bug. Turned out I had two threads reading the same socket. Once I ensured I had only single thread reading the socket, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I finally solved it in 2014 itself, I forgot to update here. It wasn't any asio bug. Turned out I had two threads reading the same socket. Once I ensured I had only single thread reading the socket, the problem went away.